# Cannot get text to wrap around sidebar container in WordPress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, containers, word-wrap

The structure:

```css
#main {}

#content-wrap {
  width: 100%
}

#sidebar-wrap {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content-wrap"></div>
  <div id="sidebar-wrap"></div>
</div>
```

The idea is to get the content text to wrap around the not so tall sidebar.
The theme defaults to two side-by-side containers, with content set at 70% width. I change that width to 100% to attempt the wrap, but drives the sidebar below the content.

Have tried `isplay: visible` `clear: both`, but nothing works. I have also tried `vertical-align: top` which also does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
div#content-wrap {float: left;}
```

to your css. I am not sure if you are wanting to float the content panel or not, but at some point you will need to

```
clear: both; -- or clear left/right depending on what you are wanting to happen
```

for other objects to acknowledge their existence (i.e. so that a footer attaches to the bottom).

Comment: The content-wrap is floated left now. I have tried both ways. I am now thinking there must be some formatting higher up in the css that is affecting the little issue. Also, most WordPress sites you see out there are not doing what I would like to do, so I'm wondering what's up with that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="main">
<div id="content-wrap">
    <div id="sidebar-wrap"></div>
    content-wrap content goes here
</div>
</div>
```

Should do it

See http://jsfiddle.net/tvmSV/2/

Comment: Okay, this would involved editing the theme's php files as the structure needs to change? I've done some php editing, but this is beyond me. I don't mind hacking the theme, if necessary. Of course, will kill updates to the theme, but that's okay. Will be back at it later, and for the rest of the day!

Comment: Alternatively, if you're able to just move #sidebar-wrap _above_ #content-wrap, that would also work - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tvmSV/3/) - and would probably be simpler to hack.

Comment: Cool! Any idea what files need to be hacked? page.php? I'm limited on php. I've registered sidebars, added logos etc. but that's it. Thanks!